# Give an example of a $f$ such that $\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R})\not\ni f\in\mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R})$ $(1\leq p\leq q)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lp-spaces

(a) Give an example of a $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R})\not\ni f\in\mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R})$ for $1\leq p\leq q$

(b) Give an example of a $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\not\ni f\in\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $ p \in[1,\infty)$

---

$f\in\mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R})$ if

$$\int_\mathbb{R} |f|^q \;d\mu < \infty$$

(a)

$$f(x) = e^{{-x}^{1/q}}  \textbf{1}_{[0, \infty)}$$

Then

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left| e^{{-x}^{1/q}}  \textbf{1}_{[0, \infty)}\right|^q \;d\mu =
\int_{[0,\infty)} e^{-x}   \;d\mu = 1$$

$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left| e^{{-x}^{1/q}}  \textbf{1}_{[0, \infty)}\right|^p \;d\mu =
\int_{[0,\infty)} e^{{-x}^{p/q}}   \;d\mu = \infty$$

Seems like a complicated example (you need complex analysis to prove the last integral does not converge), but I cannot think of anything simpler.

I believe, there should be a much simpler example.

(b)

$f\in\mathcal{L}^\infty$ if $f$ is bounded almost everywhere i.e. $|f
|\leq c \quad a.e$ for some $c\geq0$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x&x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
0&otherwise
\end{cases}$$

$f(x)$ is not bounded and $$\int_\mathbb{R} |f|^p \;d\mu = 0$$ for all $p\in[0,\infty)$

I need help verifying these examples and suggestions on other maybe easier/more intuitive examples.

Comment: Look at $\frac{1}{x^{1/2} \log x}1_{x \in (0,1)}$ and  $\frac{1}{x^{1/2} \log x}1_{x \in (1,\infty)}$

Comment: You made an error in both of your examples: $\lvert e^{-x^{1/q}} \rvert^q \neq e^{-x}$ but $\lvert e^{-x^{1/q}} \rvert^q = e^{-q x^{1/q}}$. 
And in b), the function is bounded almost everywhere since $\|f(x) \| \leq 0$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero.

Comment: @Demophilus Thanks, I understand where I have gone wrong.\

Comment: Also note that you probably should write $p<q$ instead of $p \leq q$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry but I cannot figure out how to use your hint.

Comment: For what $p$ would you say $\frac{1}{x^{1/2} \log x}1_{x \in (1,\infty)} \in L^p$ ?

Comment: @reuns For $p=\infty$? The function is bounded but the integral doesn't seem to be for $p<\infty$

Comment: Try again with $p =1,2,3$

Comment: @reruns I remember now that $\int 1/x^p$ will converge on $x>1$ if $p>1$

Comment: @reruns I still don't understand the purpose of the logarithm

Comment: For what $p$ did you find it is $\in L^p$ ?

Comment: @reuns p=3  right?

Comment: What $p=3 $? Since the function is bounded the answer is $p \ge a$ or $p > a$ for some $a$. In general $f \in L^p$ for $p \in (a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ or $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some nice counterexamples:

For a): $f(x) = x^{-1/p} 1_{(1,+\infty)}$.

For b): $f(x) = \log(x)l 1_{(0,1)}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. In b) the OP asks for an example of an $L^p$ function with $p \in [1,+\infty)$ such that $f \not \in L^\infty$. The fact that $f \not \in L^\infty$ is intentional, not an error.

Comment: It meant $f $ is in every $L^p, p < \infty$ and not in $L^\infty$ thus we need something like $\log(x) 1_{x \in (0,1)}$

Comment: Ok that is more clear. I didn't really interpret it that way, but it's a good example so I'll edit it in. Thank you.